# Simple Firebase validation rule (isNumber) not working

Tags: validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database structure ([Firebase Console - Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDK2Y.gif)):

```
{
"competitors": {
    0: {
        "name": "Arnold",
        "position": 1
    },
    1: ...
}
```

Rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,

        "competitors": {
            "$competitor": {
                "position": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to simulate adding a string value from the console simulator, the rule works fine - a violation of the rule is reported. But when I really add or change the position's value as a string (from Firebase console) the value is added without error.

How to correctly set up a validation rule permitting only number values?

**UPDATE** (based on Oussema's comment)

The following alternative form gives the same result:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,

        "competitors": {
            "$competitor": {
                ".validate": "newData.child('position').isNumber()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to read the value by using `val()` like this :

```
".validate": "newData.val().isNumber()"
```

Comment: I tried it. But got this error: "No such method/property 'isNumber'"

Comment: ".validate": "newData.child(yourfield).isNumber()" try this way

Comment: Having a very similar issue here. I am yet to find a result.

Answer (score 0):

### You are already doing it right but here's the catch

> The firebase rules won't work if you edit the data directly through
>   the `firebase console`. Instead, try to update or set the data using
>   firebase SDK and it should throw the error `PERMISSION_DENIED`

---

Example: Consider a very simple db

```
{
  number_only: 3
}
```

Very simple rules

```
{
  "rules":{
     "number_only":{
       ".write": true,
       ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
     }
  }
}
```

Test it:

1. Set number_only to "str" via console - shall work
2. Using Firebase Javascript SDK - `firebase.database.ref('number_only').set('str')` - would throw error